# I can no longer install netcat6 for IPv6 support

Tags: software-installation, netcat

I am trying to install netcat 6 to deal with ipv6. However, for some reason I can't install it.
I tried to upgrade by `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install netcat`
That didn't work. I tried to install it like this also with no luck:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netcat6
```

Edit: 
so according to the website: http://deepspace6.net/projects/netcat6.html

netcat6 is no longer supported because netcat should support ipv6 now. However, it is not really doing so even after the upgrade.

```
nc: invalid option -- '6'
```

Comment: It is not in the repos. You will have to try a ppa , install from Source, or find an alternate

Comment: @Panther Thanks. Check my edit if you don't mind.

Comment: Ryan, from your own link netcat6 is discontinued since the original utilities have gained native support for IPv6.  You answered your own question.  Maybe create your own answer telling us which one did you chose after?  That will help someone else looking for the answer.

Comment: @Marlon I actually thought netcat6 was a newer version of the regular netcat. That's why I did the apt-get upgrade netcat to begin with. I want the ipv6 support on netcat native (which doesn't seem to be possible in my version even though I just upgraded it to the last one).  That's why the question is unfortunately still unanswered.

Comment: Took my own advice.  People dont like it when you answer something in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the naked `netcat` package is the traditional (read older) utility.  The one you want is `netcat-openbsd` which is not mentioned exactly like that in your link but it's mentioned as the openbsd utility.  Run the below commands in the terminal to remove the older one and install the new one.

- First: `sudo apt-get -y remove netcat-traditional netcat`
- Then: `sudo apt-get -y install netcat-openbsd`

After that you can use `netcat` or `nc`.

Comment: Gotcha ! Thanks very much for the explanation. I didn't know that there were 2 of them